# how to create or dock dockable pane on full client screen MFC?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-2012

i want to create a dockable pane full size on client screen i want it load full size on client screen by default when application load at start point.i have tried with many ways like override setwindowpos() method and setminsize() method but it didn't work window not called this method on cdockable pane here is my code on oncreate() method in parent window

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
BOOL bNameValid;
// Create output window
CString strOutputWnd;
bNameValid = strOutputWnd.LoadString(IDS_OUTPUT_WND);
ASSERT(bNameValid);

if (!m_wndOutput.Create(strOutputWnd, this, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), TRUE, ID_VIEW_OUTPUTWND, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_BOTTOM | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create Output window\n");
        return FALSE; // failed to create
    }

m_wndOutput.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY );
int screen_height=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
int screen_width =GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);    
m_wndOutput.SetMinSize(CSize(screen_height,screen_width)
m_wndOutput.CalcFixedLayout(FALSE,TRUE);
DockPane(&m_wndOutput);
}
```

Comment: Check this out https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493218/Understanding-CDockablePane

Comment: I already downloaded it CDockablePane and checked but not found any appropriate exact solution of this problem can u suggest me the proper solution i am stucked ..